# I Need Help Adjusting This Submit Code Please

Tags: javascript, html

I'm ABSOLUTELY new to coding so please bear with me.

I am currently using this code:

```
 <form action="LINK GOES HERE" target="_blank">

    <a href="#"></a>
</form>
<script>
    $('a').click(function () {
        // do something you want ...
        $('form').submit();
    });
</script>
```

(Never mind the "// do something you want", or explain it to me, I'm not really sure what that is for... I found this code somewhere on this website)

So what happens is when I submit the form, it's supposed to redirect me to the next website, as normal, BUT it also simultaneously opens a new tab and redirects to a DIFFERENT website.

I have this sequence of websites.

The code is on the 3rd website in the sequence.

Now, when I paste the code and preview JUST THAT 3rd PAGE, the code works fine... Redirects and opens new tab.

BUT, when I start from the beginning of the websites sequence, when I get to the 3rd page, it DOESN'T open a new tab and only redirects.

Can someone put in a full code of how I am to fix this so that it works no matter where you start from the sequence?

I'll post the link of the websites in case my explanations are terrible. When it asks you to put in an email address, just put in a dummy email.

This is the beginning of the website sequence:
https://www.funkywithans.com/beginners

This is just the 3rd page:
https://www.funkywithans.com/email-form

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Nobody here is going to click on random links.  Any relevant code should be posted in the question.   Thanks

Comment: @OldProgrammer 'Nobody here is going to click on random links' That's where your wrong. If I can save question form getting destroyed by people like you I will click on any link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The // do something you want

The `//` indicated a comment. That means that it won't get executed. the `do something here` is whoever wrote the code saying that if you wanted to do anything else before going to the next page. If you just wan't to go to the next page you can ignore that

### The Actual Problem

I think the problem is in the second page. When you are redirecting on the second page you go to `/email` the 3rd page link you gave goes to `/form` On the `/form` page is opens a new tab, but not on the `/email` page.

What you want to do is to change the `action` on the `form` to the `/form` on the second page (`/beginner-page`).

### The Super-Duper Simplified Version

On your second page you have something that looks like this

```html
 <form action="LINK GOES HERE" target="_blank">

    <a href="#"></a>
</form>
<script>
    $('a').click(function () {
        // do something you want ...
        $('form').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Basically that part that says `LINK GOES HERE` is something like `https://www.funkywithans.com/email` (at least that's where it take you). The third link you gave goes to `https://www.funkywithans.com/form` (if redirects there from `https://www.funkywithans.com/email-form`). You need to replace `https://www.funkywithans.com/email` with `https://www.funkywithans.com/form`) **ON THE SECOND PAGE**

Just a note. More code would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reponse.

Comment: So I'm kind of confused in what I need to do to fix this...

Comment: Can you tell me please where I have to put what, as if you're talking to someone who doesn't even know what code is...

Comment: @Awesomous I have edited my answer. Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: That's odd... because I didn't put any code on the second page...

Comment: And what exactly is the "third link"?
thank you for your time and help btw.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH................. Hold on a sec.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH......... I GOT IT!
I get it I get it I get it!
Thank you SO much for your time and your help!
I REALLY appreciate it.
You're awesome man!

Comment: @Awesomous No problem. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @Awesomous Could you mark my answer as correct so that other people know that it worked?

Comment: I'd be glad to... How?

Comment: @Awesomous There should be a greyed out checkmark under where you can up vote and downvote. Click on it and it should turn green. Then you and I both get some reputation.